# Creating saved target group in facebook audience

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I need to create Saved Target Group in facebook programmatically like PowerEditor does it here https://www.facebook.com/ads/manage/powereditor.

During inspecting the browser's console when saving through the Power Editor I've discovered that such kind of an endpoint is used:

"https://graph.facebook.com/v2.2/act_@AD_ACCOUNT_ID@/audiences", but the method called is encrypted and there is no information about this kind of endpoint in the facebook API documentation.

Seems like Power Editor uses more extended API or not all the API is well documented.

Did anybody experience something similar?

Thanks

Comment: I would LOVE to know how to do this too (if Facebook's API even allows it). I.e. How can I use the Facebook API to create a "Saved Audience" (not "Custom Audience")? I've already looked at docs (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/audiences-api and https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/custom-audience-api) and haven't found any clues. I also wish I could figure out how to have the Audience Insights webpage be able to "open" Saved Audiences (created within Power Editor or Ads Manager).

Answer (score 0):

Not all of the functionality available in Power Editor is available in the public API or vice versa -

If what you're asking about is not in the public API documentation, it's not part of the API that is available publicly -

It would be dangerous to assume that an undocumented endpoint will continue to work or that it works in a specific way based on observing another app (Power Editor) calling it

Answer (score -1):

You can use saved_audiences API.
Here is Graph Explorer request examples:

POST:
[https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/765026780221012?method=POST&path=act_&Fsaved_audiences&version=v2.5&name=foo&targeting={ "age_min":18, "age_max":65, "page_types":[ "desktop-and-mobile-and-external" ], "geo_locations":{ "countries":[ "US" ], "location_types":[ "home" ] } }](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/765026780221012?method=POST&path=act_<AD_ACCOUNT_ID>&Fsaved_audiences&version=v2.5&name=foo&targeting=%7B%20%22age_min%22:18,%20%22age_max%22:65,%20%22page_types%22:[%20%22desktop-and-mobile-and-external%22%20],%20%22geo_locations%22:%7B%20%22countries%22:[%20%22US%22%20],%20%22location_types%22:[%20%22home%22%20]%20%7D%20%7D)

GET ALL:
[https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/765026780221012?method=GET&path=act_%2Fsaved_audiences&version=v2.5](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/765026780221012?method=GET&path=act_%3CAD_ACCOUNT_ID%3E%2Fsaved_audiences&version=v2.5)